# Where should I store my github O-Auth token when writing a shell script?

Tags: bash, shell, security, github, travis-ci

I am writing a shell script that will push code from my "testing" branch to my "master" branch. I am using Travis-CI to test my code and run the shell script, which is initiated every time a new commit is pushed to "testing". I can see the shell script running within the Travis-CI job log but I am getting the following error:

`remote: Invalid username or password.`

`fatal: Authentication failed for '<repo>'`

I know it is my password that is invalid because I have configured my username and email earlier in the script.

Now, my main question is how and where should I store my github O-Auth key? I don't want to hard code it into my shell script because then everyone will be able to see it. Any ideas on how I can create a script to push my code without giving away my password?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your secrets into environmental variables which you can reference in your script.

export MY_OAUTH='some oauth key'

Then you can use the variable $MY_OAUTH in your script.

If you want to make the environmental variable permanent see this:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/117467/how-to-permanently-set-environmental-variables

Answer (score 0):

Travis provides a facility to encrypt/decrypt files and variables to be used in your build process. The simplest way is via the web interface for your project on travis. Click on `More options -> Setttings` and you'll see a form to enter name/value pairs. You can then directly use the name entered, but make sure you properly escape special chars etc.
[Travis docs](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/environment-variables/#Defining-Variables-in-Repository-Settings)